Landsat 5 RGB displaying wrong colours GEE
I'm accessing a Landsat 5 image on GEE from the Collection 2 Tier 2 dataset (tier 1 is not available for these images). I'm displaying in B3/2/1 (i.e. R/G/B) but the white ice and snow shows up as yellow. This is not an issue with Landsat 7 etc.
Visualize code:
 LANDSAT_5:{bands:['B3','B2','B1'],min:0,max:0.8},

Image (the yellow is ice, the dark is ocean)


Why are you setting the max reflectance to 0.8? What happens when you change that value to 1?

That works well on other images for visualization. It doesn't make a significant difference to the yellow issue.

Try this code to access the data you want from GEE based on the collection date for the image you are interested in. (adjust filter dates on line 2)
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T2_L2')
    .filterDate('2000-11-01', '2001-01-01');

// Applies scaling factors.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBand, null, true);
}

dataset = dataset.map(applyScaleFactors);

var visualization = {
  bands: ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.8,
};

Map.setCenter(-83, 24, 8);

Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, 'True Color (321)');

The important thing is to apply the scaling factors so that your data are in reflectance and not digital numbers. Once you have done that, you can tweak the way the colors are rendered by adjusting the saturation value max: 0.8
